# What is Record ID in flowbuilder?

Tags: flow-builder

Here is the snip of action need to set
[image: here is the snip of action need to set please open the given link]

here is the error snip received
[image: here is the error snip received please open link]

What will be recordid need to put for triggering mail alert for Automated flow(non Trigger)- through REST API.

when is set their $user.id and run flow manually I received error!

please help how to trigger email alert with autolaunched flows(Non Trigger) with restapi, one should receive mail when this flow containing email alert is triggered.

Comment: Hi Akhil, I hope you have use Email alert in the flow. Can you edit your question confirm on which object is Email Alert defined? Because the Email alert uses some template where fields from object would be referenced.

Comment: For lead object I created email template and email  alert but i need to know what should I put in that recordid field!

Comment: How is this flow called and is it passing any input parameters?

Comment: I am using java code to with rest api with following URL :  /services/data/v50.0/actions/custom/flow/Flow_mail

Comment: RecordID will be input parameter I guess?

Comment: So you have to pass the lead id to the flow and define a resource of variable and keep available for input for the same .

Comment: I have done the same this created one new resource whose api name I put leadid and kept available for input then in record id I used the variable {!leadid.Id} like this and when I run it after activating I received the same error:                                                      An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow
An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information.

Comment: unable to understand !

Comment: If the variable of type text which you created it leadid then the variable will be {!leadid} and when you debug the flow give the lead id as input